# min{wi, W − w} function in knapsack algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm, knapsack-problem

```
Algorithm FractionalKnapsack(S, W ):
Input: Set S of items, such that each item i ∈ S has a positive benefit bi and a
positive weight wi; positive maximum total weight W
Output: Amount xi of each item i ∈ S that maximizes the total benefit while
not exceeding the maximum total weight W
for each item i ∈ S do 
 xi ← 0
 vi ← bi/wi // value index of item i 
w ← 0 // total weight
while w < W and S ̸= ∅ do
 remove from S an item i with highest value index
 a ← min{wi, W − w} // more than W − w causes a weight overflow 
 xi ← a
 w←w+a
```

I am trying to implement the above pseudocode in Ruby, I have successfully implemented a priority queue but I just need someone to explain this line for me:

> a ← min{wi, W − w} // more than W − w causes a weight overflow

what the min function is supposed to do exactly? and how should it be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line a ← min{wi, W − w} actually gives a value to 'a' which is minimum value of w[i] and W-w.

```
if w[i] < W-w then a ← w[i]
otherwise a ← W-w
```

For the implementation you can do

```
[w[i], W-w].min
```